# Java - Libgdx : Check user's input in a textfield?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, libgdx, textfield

My if..else statement:

```
if(réponse.getText().equals("")){
            réponse.setText("");
        } else if(réponse.getText().equals("riviere")){
            game.setScreen(new Stage1(game));
            music.stop();
        }
        else if(!réponse.getText().equals("riviere")){
            ecrireLeTexte = true;
        }
```

I created a textfield and then straight away check what's in it but I'm afraid the user can't type anything before the textfield check's...

so how to check the user's input after it's typing ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking so it might be a good idea to clarify a little bit more. However, your code is also a little sloppy: why do you have the first `if` statement? It's pretty redundant. You could simply remove it and turn your `else if` into the first `if`. Furthermore, strings are a pretty fragile method to ascertain what the user's choices since they could easily misspell a word, etc. At the very least you could make the `response` string lowercase first which gives a slightly more robust comparison but still something which is hard to recommend.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Also, you seem to have just trown on every tag you could think of regardles of their relevance to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your check in your render method so it will be called each frame or set TextFieldListener to your TextField to listen for changes.

```
réponse.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char c) {
        //Here you can compare the text
    }
});
```

Also remember to set your Stage as InputProcessor fe. `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`

Comment: I don't want to get a char but I string, how can I do ?

Comment: If you want to get the whole text you should use `textField.getText()` inside listener. However if you just want to cast char c to string you can use `String.valueOf(c)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I didn't get it, can you show me on my code below ?

Comment: réponse.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char c) {

                if(réponse.getText().equals("vie")){
                    System.out.println("okok" );
                    game.setScreen(new BienOuej(game));
                    music.stop();
                }
                else if(!réponse.getText().equals("vie")) {
                    game.setScreen(new Druide2(game));
                    music.stop();
                }
            }
        });

Comment: if it's : textField.getText(); inside listener, it returns me only 1 character not the full string "vie"

Comment: Listener will be called after each key typed, not words. Put just these lines in your listener and you will see what I am talking about: `Gdx.app.log("Text", textField.getText()); Gdx.app.log("Character", String.valueOf(c));` Fe. when I want to type `ok` I will get a log `Text: o
Character: o
Text: ok
Character: k`

Comment: how can I do to get the word typed ? I want my listener to be called after word not after each character